# Can't build Ubuntu Kernel: Why does "make mrproper" get rid of debian directory? How do I build a Ubuntu/Trusty kernel without debian/rules?

Tags: 14.04, kernel, modprobe

I've been trying to build a Ubuntu Kernel for the past several weeks. (Actually, I don't need the kernel, I just need snd-aloop.ko, which is missing from the Ubuntu 14 server distributions, it's in 12, but I can't find a way to build just this module that works on the latest released Ubuntu that I'm running (Ubunty/trusty Linux vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 3.13.0-30-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 4 21:40:53 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)

I followed the directions on the official Ubuntu site and get this error

```
Using /home/vagrant/linux-3.13.0 as source for kernel
/home/vagrant/linux-3.13.0 is not clean, please run 'make mrproper'
in the '/home/vagrant/linux-3.13.0' directory.
```

Among the things mrproper does, is delete the "debian" directory!

```
CLEAN   /home/vagrant/linux-3.13.0/debian/
CLEAN   .config
```

How do I build without the debian directory, as the official Ubuntu documentation tells me to build the kernel with the "rules" script in the debian directory

```
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
 DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS=parallel=3 AUTOBUILD=1 fakeroot debian/rules binary-generic
```

Note that I run the debian/rules clean before my build, but it isn't clean enough for Mr. Proper! Ill get that message:

```
/home/vagrant/linux-3.13.0 is not clean, please run 'make mrproper'
```

I have done nothing to the source tree other than set the .config file to match the system I'm running on. All I really want is a snd-aloop.ko that will load on my system. Why is Ubuntu so screwed up?

Comment: snd-aloop.ko is included on my 14.04 computers. I also see it specified as a module build in all of my kernel config files. As for the kernel compile stuff, yes it is very annoying. I only use (the old fashioned way now)[https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile#Alternate_Build_Method_.28B.29:_The_Old-Fashioned_Debian_Way]. And, actually don't even compile the ubuntu kernel anymore, I only comopile the kernel.org one.

Comment: I do not get snd-aloop.ko on my 14.04. I'm using the one from here: https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64


Are you saying that other "14.04" distributions may be different?

Comment: I only use Ubuntu stuff from Ubuntu, and in that kernel what you want is there by default. I don't know anything about vagrantcloud.

Comment: The amazon aws Ubuntu 14 image from Amazon doesn't have it either.

Comment: Well, if you think it might help, I can paste my notes on kernel compile into an answer, but they are based on the "old fashioned way" I referenced above. It has been a few years though, as like I mentioned I don't do it that way anymore (and, due to stupid mistakes on my part, I've build the kernel several times just today)

Comment: I'm wondering if I'm not seeing it in the distros I'm getting because I'm getting "sever" distributions and someone thought the audio drivers wouldn't be useful there...

Comment: I'd like to see how a kernel compile without using the stuff in "debian/rules" works. That method, even though it's what ubuntu.org says to use, is completely broken because of the error that the tree isn't clean if a config file has changed.

Comment: Could be. As of recent releases Ubuntu makes the same kernel for both Server and Desktop. See if you can find what you want [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D).

Comment: If I do a build without changing the config file, it will build snd-aloop.ko. But modprobe refuses to load it, probably because the "SIGNATURE" string doesn't match. When I update the config file to match the .config from the /boot directory, I get that "your tree is dirty, run make mrproper, which then deletes the debian directory"

Comment: all I do is "make clean"
"time make -j8 deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-doug"

Comment: Thanks! (I wonder what all the scripts in the debian directory do, but at this point I don't care.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just ran into the same error over and over and was getting annoyed. Turns out, if you copy your kernel config .config to the root, that is what causes the issue. There should not be a .config file at the source root.

You have to run `fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs` instead and edit the config file for the proper arch.

Use these instructions: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel

Comment: Thanks! I'd vote you up, but I don't have enough "reputation" points.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I was running make oldconfig. Thank you.